# Data record for an MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd

Say that in a layout view of an MXD, I *draw* a simple rectangle.

**Does a record of this rectangle exist anywhere in the project data in a way that can be edited or duplicated?**

Reason: My team is attempting to create a graphic similar to a histogram and we would like to be able to bulk specify the placement of rectangles in the layout view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in ArcPy by cloning a graphic element that is a rectangle, and then changing its position and size properties.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/graphicelement-class.htm